# Failed to update a ServiceWorker for scope - HTTP error 400

Tags: javascript, vue.js, service-worker

I have a Vue PWA app, and in our error logs, I'm seeing hundreds of these for one particular user (myself and another person are unable to replicate this).

```
Failed to update a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://myapp.com/') with script ('https://myapp.com/service-worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (400) was received when fetching the script.
```

When I go to that URL, the service worker JS file comes up just fine.

In my vue.config.js, I have this:

```js
  pwa: {
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      swSrc: './src/sw.js',
      swDest: 'service-worker.js',
    },
  },
```

My `src/sw.js` file:

```js
/* eslint-disable */
// This is the code piece that GenerateSW mode can't provide for us.
// This code listens for the user's confirmation to update the app.
self.addEventListener('message', e => {
  if (!e.data) {
    return;
  }

  switch (e.data) {
    case 'skipWaiting':
      self.skipWaiting();
      break;
    default:
      // NOOP
      break;
  }
});

workbox.core.clientsClaim(); // Vue CLI 4 and Workbox v4, else

// The precaching code provided by Workbox.
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

The `src/registerServiceWorker.ts` file:

```js
import { register } from 'register-service-worker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    registered(registration) {
      // Check for code updates every minute
      setInterval(() => {
        registration.update();
      }, 1000 * 60);
    },
    updated(registration) {
      document.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('swUpdated', { detail: registration })
      );
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP `400`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) is a fairly generic status code that could be returned for any number of reasons.

All of the info you posted is related to your client-side code, but that does not help debug server-side issues.

Ultimately, the way to investigate this is to determine why your backend web server is returning a HTTP `400` for a subset of the incoming `https://myapp.com/service-worker.js` that it receives. The answer to that is specific to your web server setup, and looking at your server logs may give you a clue.

Comment: The files are statically hosted on AWS Amplify (similar to Netlify), so I can't access logs. As I mentioned, if I open the file in my browser, it comes up just fine. So there's some service worker weirdness going on here that probably has little to do with the server.